# Como configurar o clearOnBlur do ui-mask de maneira Inline?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, framework, mask

Há alguma maneira de configurar o ***clearOnBlur*** do *ui-mask* de maneira Inline?

De acordo com a documentação, uma das maneiras para *settar* configurações da *ui-mask* é por ***Config Provider*** (ou algo assim), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
app.config(['uiMask.ConfigProvider', function(uiMaskConfigProvider) {
  uiMaskConfigProvider.clearOnBlur(false);      
}
```

*Exemplo extraído de:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask*

Seguindo a lógica sugerida para configuração do ***Placeholder Char***, que é algo do tipo :

```
<input type="text" (...) ui-mask-placeholder-char="_"/>
```

Ocorreu-me a hipótese de usar desta maneira:

```
<input type="text" (...) ui-mask-clear-on-blur="false"/>
```

... porem, como podem imaginar, não funciona.

Observando em outros fóruns, no SO gringo, foi sugerido algo interessantemente plausível:

```
<input type="text" (...) ui-options="{clearOnBlur: false}"/>
```

*Exemplo extraído de:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574151/how-to-set-autoclear-on-angular-ui-mask-to-false#answer-29381277*

... porem também não funcionou.

Acredito que hajam outras maneiras de se configurar via *Directives* ou até mesmo *Filters*, mas há alguma maneira ***inline***?